# HTML images not aligned when they are not the same image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm making an image view thing, and am having some trouble with aligning the images. When I have two of the same image in a row, it will be aligned, but when the images are different, the second image will go lower than the first. Here is screenshot [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/3j2lp4). Here is my html and css
**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="images">
            <div class="image" onClick="showimage('users/images/username/battlefield4_maars.png','battlefield4_maars.png','3.91MB','png');">
                <img src="users/images/username/battlefield4_maars.png">
                <div class="normaltext">battlefield4_maars.png</div>
            </div>
            <div class="image" onClick="showimage('users/images/username/dark_souls_2.jpg','dark_souls_2.jpg','363KB','jpg');">
                <img src="users/images/username/dark_souls_2.jpg">
                <div class="normaltext">dark_souls_2.jpg</div>
            </div>
            <div class="image" onClick="showimage('users/images/username/thief.jpg','thief.jpg','393KB','jpg');">
                <img src="users/images/username/thief.jpg">
                <div class="normaltext">thief.jpg</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
#images {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.image {
    height: 200px;
    width: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.image img {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Does it change when you add a 3rd image with its text below the image is only 1 line instead of 2?

Comment: It actually was the word-wrap that was making it like this, since there were two lines. I added a php function to shorten the text and add '...' to it and now it works, thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this:

```
#images {display:block;}
.image {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: set the #images to display:block; instead of display:inline-block; and add the vertical-align:top; to .image